# Низкий FPS из за физики | Процедурный MeshColider

Tags: c#, unity3d, mesh

Как  оптимизировать физику на Unity?
Через `Profiler` на Unity я посмотрел что больше всего нагружает физика, а физичный объект у меня только вода. У меня есть пластины с динамическим мешом который изменяется с помощью `perlinNoise` каждый кадр и динамическим меш-колайдером который меняется с помощью этого куска:

```
Mesh myMesh = this.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
DestroyImmediate(this.GetComponent<MeshCollider>());
gameObject.AddComponent<MeshCollider>();
GetComponent<MeshCollider>().sharedMesh = myMesh;
```

Edit:
Вот сам код который генерирует воду:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class WaterNoise : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float power = 3;
    public float scale = 1;
    public float timeScale = 1;

    float offsetX;
    float offsetY;
    MeshFilter mf;

    private void Start()
    {
        mf = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
        GenNoise();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        GenNoise();
        offsetX += Time.deltaTime * timeScale;
        offsetY += Time.deltaTime * timeScale;
    }

    void GenNoise()
    {
        Vector3 myPos = transform.localPosition;
        Vector3[] vertices = mf.mesh.vertices;

        for(int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
        {
            vertices[i].y = CalculateHeight(vertices[i].x + myPos.x, vertices[i].z + myPos.z) * power;
        }

        Mesh myMesh = this.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
        DestroyImmediate(this.GetComponent<MeshCollider>());
        gameObject.AddComponent<MeshCollider>();
        GetComponent<MeshCollider>().sharedMesh = myMesh;

        mf.mesh.vertices = vertices;
    }

    float CalculateHeight(float x, float y)
    {
        float xCoord = x * scale + offsetX;
        float yCoord = y * scale + offsetY;

        return Mathf.PerlinNoise(xCoord, yCoord);
    }
}
```

Приложение однопоточное.

Comment: Не стоит каждый кадр "искать" коллайдер `GetComponent`. Кэшируйте значение.

Comment: К сожалению это не дало большого прироста FPS

Comment: А можно **весь** код метода, а не его кусок?

Comment: Добавил весь скрипт для удобства.

Comment: Какой у вас w h обьекта куска воды? Если например 16 x 16 то создайте массив 16 x 16 x 20 (20 кадров) * 4 (размер int32) это будет массив на 20 кбайт. В массив запишите значения, а потом вместо CalculateHeight например - просто значение с массива берите.

Comment: Повторюсь что я проверял что лагает через Profiler, а лагает физика, а не скрипты.

Comment: @BrekWorld приложите скриншот профайлера.

Comment: Профайлер: https://imgur.com/a/gFNEVlN

Comment: Информация для вопроса - в вопрос, а не в комментарии. Да и скриншот бесполезен, прикрепите лог того, что конкретно лагает, на недографике юнити этого не понять.

Comment: А где тогда взять те логи?

Comment: @BrekWorld https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/Manual/ProfilerCPU.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Важно!

Никогда, нет, не так. **НИКОГДА** не изменяйте меш коллайдера в рантайме. Физический движок работает не так, как кажется со стороны. Чтобы меш действительно правильно и, главное, **быстро** просчитывал столкновения, движок производит некоторые достаточно дорогие манипуляции, которые происходят на этапе инициализации компонента `MeshCollider`.

Решение? Не делать то, что вы пытаетесь сделать.

---

1. Зачем **каждый** фрейм уничтожать компоненты и тут же создавать их заново?

   ```
   Mesh myMesh = this.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;   // копия меши
   DestroyImmediate(this.GetComponent<MeshCollider>());  // уничтожения оригинального коллайдера
   gameObject.AddComponent<MeshCollider>();              // добавление нового коллайдера
   GetComponent<MeshCollider>().sharedMesh = myMesh;     // обновление нового коллайдера
   ```

---

2. [`Mesh.vertices` возвращает **копию** массива вершин](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-vertices.html)

> Returns a copy of the vertex positions or assigns a new vertex
>   positions array.

Поскольку меш изменяет только этот скрипт, то можно просто закэшировать этот массив 1 раз и не вызывать каждый физический фрейм `Mesh.vertices`, GC скажет вам спасибо:

```
private Mesh _sharedMesh;
private Vector3[] _vertices;

private MeshCollider _meshCollider;

private void Awake()
{
    _sharedMesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh;
    _vertices = _sharedMesh.vertices;

    _meshCollider =  GetComponent<MeshCollider>();
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    // изменяем _vertices

    // изменяем полигональную сетку
    _sharedMesh.vertices = _vertices;
    _sharedMesh.RecalculateBounds();

    // отдаем эту сетку физическому движку
    // это побудит его заново пересчитать сетку для физических взаимодействий
    _meshCollider.sharedMesh = _sharedMesh;
}
```